# Using Umbraco's text editor, how to use ID's?

Tags: umbraco

I'm currently working on an Umbraco project; which I hate with a passion, and I need a drop down list. I've already gone over the usual select and option tags for a dropdown selector and that obviously didn't work, but we may be able to use a HTML/CSS dropdown menu in place of it. I got a menu setup and everything but once I paste my code into the text editor, save, and go back in all of my ID's are removed BUT all the classes are still there.

Is there any way I can keep Umbraco from removing these ID's?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

this should be what you're after hopefully 
http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/customizing-the-wysiwyg-rich-text-editor-%28tinymce%29/allow-any-markup-in-the-tinymce-editor

Comment: Thank you, and do you know if Umbraco has any problems after doing this? I hate Umbraco so far, it's crashed like 3 times and has given me a crazy experience I do not wish to repeat. xD

Comment: I've mostly only had good experiences with Umbraco, crashed as in crashed the browser?  best place to get help if you're having trouble is over at http://our.umbraco.org/

Comment: Remember that you're trying to lay out HTML in a rich TEXT editor, that's not what it is for and you will keep having bad experiences with it. Besides, will your website editors know enough HTML not to mess up your carefully crafted div id's? I hope so, but expect the worst.